# Get cursor position in Atom

Tags: coffeescript, atom-editor

When looking at the Atom APIs for a package that I'm writing, it said that you use the Cursor class to access cursor information. I'm trying to get the cursor buffer position, so I tried using `getBufferPosition()`. The entire line of code was:

```
cursorRow = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor().Cursor.getBufferPosition()[0]
```

to get just the row. However, it keeps throwing this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBufferPosition' of undefined
```

This is all in CoffeeScript, by the way. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, because the APIs say that `getBufferPosition` is a method of the Cursor class, so that should work. What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to figure this out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`getCursorBufferPosition` of `TextEditor`](https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.23.2/TextEditor#instance-getCursorBufferPosition), i.e.

```
cursorPosition = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor().getCursorBufferPosition()
```

The error you're seeing is telling you that there is no property named `Cursor` on the text editor. There may well be a `getBufferPosition` defined on the `Cursor` class, but you're not calling it on an instance of `Cursor`, but on `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to this forum and it just slipped my mind.

Comment: No problem! Seeing that you're new is why I brought it up. I'm glad that you found the answer useful!